# SQL joining tables with multiple tables

Tags: sql, join

I am having a lot of issues with my SQL homework. Specifically once I have to deal with more than two tables to acquire the needed solution I get stuck.

An example would be List the order number and order date for each order that ether placed by Almondton general store and that contains an order line for a fire engine.

I tried to use the following code to accomplish this.

```
select order_num, order_date
from orders
where exists (select *
              from customer, order_line, item
              where orders.customer_num = customer.customer_num
                and customer_name = 'Almondton Genreal Store'
                 or orders.order_num = order_line.order_num
                and order_line.item_num = item.item_num
                and description = 'fire truck');
```

I need to know in general how to deal with using more than two tables at once.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Answer (score 0):

You want the order number and date from all orders where the customer name is `Almondton General Store` and the item being purchased is `fire truck`.  You can simply join together the four tables to get your result:

```
SELECT o.order_num, o.order_date
FROM orders o
INNER JOIN customer c
    ON o.customer_num = c.customer_num
INNER JOIN order_line ol
    ON o.order_num = ol.order_num
INNER JOIN item i
    ON ol.item_num = i.item_num
WHERE c.customer_name = 'Almondton General Store' AND i.description = 'fire truck'
```